# Looking for thin internal wall insulation for solid brick wall

Tags: insulation

My solid brick 1800s house in south Britain, it is semi detached. I am considering internal insulating some of the walls on the detached size to reduce heat loss a little. The idea would be to simply attach something to the plaster walls, possibly plasterboard over and adjust the skirting board, electrical sockets accordingly

I don't want to lose much space so what is an effective thin material I can use. I'm happy to pay more for a more expensive material to reduce the thickness required.

Comment: Would you adhere this to the plaster? This would be very difficult to remove, should you or anyone want to do so. Is your shared wall a lot warmer than the exterior walls? Are the walls a double brick construction with a space in between? I don't think there is currently a workable solution to the problem of insulating these old houses in Britain . . . at any price.

Comment: They are double brick, but I there is no cavity. I dont see any reason to need to remove them. My logic is when using a radiator calculator to calculate the correct radiator size the number of external walls in a room have quite an effect, I havent actually measured a difference between walls. I don't see any reason why I would need to remove it, after all plaster is also difficult to remove if somebody decide they wanted to remove that. What effect would adding a small batten and then plasterboard with metallic backing have, and arent there superior products available

Comment: I did not mean removal of the plaster, but rather removal of the insulation should the insulation fail to achieve its objective and be considered unaesthetic. To try to reduce the high fuel consumption of heating a structure like this, perhaps a better route is to consider controls for the radiators which allow the input to them to be reduced when the room is not occupied.

Comment: I'm just making the point that plaster is difficult to remove but doesnt stop us using it, why should insulation fail. My radiators have controls, I just want to try an minimize wasteful heating. e.g if I bathroom tiled a wall I assume the tiles would offer some additonal insulation (but not much), surely there must be something I can specifically do instead that is designed to reduce heating loss.

Comment: See this, including answers and comments:  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/16997/how-should-i-insulate-the-walls-and-ceilings-of-this-1920s-semi-detached-brick?rq=1